# button event still works with button disabled

Tags: java, swing

```
private void button_Clicked_download(MouseEvent e) {
      button_dl.setEnabled(false);
      System.out.println("Button Clicked.");
}
```

When I click the button the button looks disabled. However the button still executes the code under the MouseEvent and I see "Button Clicked." in the debug console.

How can I make it so if the button is clicked it ignores the code and is indeed disabled?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> However the button still executes the code under the **MouseEvent** and I see "Button Clicked." in the debug console.

This is exactly why you shouldn't use a MouseListener with a JButton but rather an ActionListener.  The solution is of course obvious -- to get rid of the MouseListener and instead add an ActionListener to the JButton of interest.

Comment: Thanks. I forgot about the ActionListener. I changed it to that and it works perfectly now. Thank you. =)

Answer (score 2):

you need to use an ActionListener instead of MouseClickListener.

your button is logically clicked even if it is disabled so click event will execute

Answer (score 2):

There is actually a very simple way of enabling and disabling a button in java which uses a Mouse Listener.

```
class HoldListen extends MouseAdapter {

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        JButton bt = (JButton)e.getSource();

        if (!bt.isEnabled()) {
            return;
        }

        // Do code 
    }
}
```

I found your question while trying to create something similar and this is how I solved it.
All the MouseListener's methods return void so it works out quite nice. In my situation going back to an ActionListener would have required a lot of extra work while a MouseListener was perfect for the job. Press set a variable which Release undid and another thread used the variable in a ongoing simulation.